# Better Way to Clone Current Operating System?

Tags: linux, backup, operating-systems

This Question maybe so bad, I am Newbie if you dont like, please ignore this, but I was thinking about something tools to creating , packaging current operating system with current configuration.

simplify you can import , export current operatin system to another computer, like copy and paste. then in on that computer have same data like another one is copied.

by the way i really dont know how to explain this situation, I need this for automatically clone current system (so,partition,all stuff).

somebody can help me out with this ?

Comment: folow this guide and tell us http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone

Comment: @FranciscoTapia - You need to shut down the live OS and run Clonezilla from an independent installation, so this is not something that can be done automatically, as the questioner requires. I am unaware of software to do this in Linux, but I use Norton Ghost on Windows, which saves a running partition, and I think there are other products that do the same. In Linux I make an occasional off-line partition back-up, supplemented by on-line back-ups of e-mails hourly and other updated files nightly, which is enough for my purposes.

Comment: @AFH hi,  I dont understand your point clonzilla is a live system it loads in Ram disk, he así for clone if he wants sync he should así for sync right??

Comment: @FranciscoTapia - Under "Limitations" on the [Clonezilla site](http://clonezilla.org), there are "Differential/incremental backup is not implemented yet." and "Online imaging/cloning is not implemented yet. The partition to be imaged or cloned has to be unmounted." - you can't do that on the running OS partition.

Comment: He said my clone my current, nvm its on hold

Comment: hi i will try to clear my question, the important  is make a image (singgle file / .iso or something) for current operating system, then can be clone to another computer that  no have operating system, so in that computer after cloned have same data and same operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried using the tool, but have you heard of clonezilla?

http://clonezilla.org/

I would give it a try.

If you have WDS (Windows Deployment Services) available I would try capturing an image of a machine and deploying it to new computers.